# NTT - Transformation of Polynomials in Kyber

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, kyber

In Kyber with $q=3329$, we end up with a field that das 256th roots of unity, when we apply the chinese remainder theorem (CRT) for such a field, it may look like, according to a post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/105971/related-to-ntt-implementation-in-crystal-kyber):

$$\mathbb{F}_{3329}[x]/(x^{256}+1)\cong\prod_{i=0}^{127}\mathbb{F}_{3329}[x]/(x^2-\zeta^{2i+1}),$$

My question is, why we can then transform a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{255}f_ix^i$ into a list say e.g.

$$\hat{f}=(\hat{f}_{2i}+x\hat{f}_{2i+1})_{i=0}^{127}.$$

The isomorphism suggests that we are dealing with polynomials with degree $\leq 1$ and there are 128 of such polynomials, so that would give us something like $(a_i+xb_i)_{i=0}^{127}$.

What interests me is how the NTT comes into play here so that we have this mapping (or how we obtain this mapping): $\hat{f}=(\hat{f}_{2i}+x\hat{f}_{2i+1})_{i=0}^{127}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained by the fact that in the linked post, the upper limit in the product is misquoted. Per page 5 of the original [Kyber documentation](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf) we have
$$X^{256}+1=\prod_{i=0}^{127}\left(X^2-\zeta^{2i+1}\right).$$

The transcription error is forgivable as the product runs over odd powers of $\zeta$ less than or equal to 255.

The list $\hat f$ is simply the list of residue polynomials of $f(X)$ with respect to the various factor polynomials $X^2-\zeta^{2i+1}$. Specifically, by the [Euclidean division lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division) for polynomials we can write
$$f(X)=(X^2-\zeta^{2i+1})q_i(X)+r_i(X)$$
for some polynomials $q_i(X)$ and $r_i(X)$ where $\deg r_i(X)<2$. If we write $\hat f_{2i}$ for the constant coefficient in $r_i(X)$ and $\hat f_{2i+1}$ for the coefficient of $X$ in $r_i(X)$, we have the list of linear polynomials that make up $\hat f(X)$. Our original polynomial can be reconstructed from this list using the polynomial Chinese remainder theorem (which can be viewed as a generalisation of Lagrange interpolation).

Comment: @TreeBook1 I've added some detail about the transformation and its inverse.